# How do I get rollup to compile at runtime with Deno?

Tags: rollup, deno

I have the following Deno code...

```
import rollup from "https://unpkg.com/rollup/dist/es/rollup.js";
const inputOptions = {
    input: "./index.mjs"
}
const outputOptions = {
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: "inline"
}

const build = async ()=>{
    const bundle = await rollup.rollup(inputOptions);
    const { output } = await bundle.generate(outputOptions);
    for (const chunkOrAsset of output) {
        if (chunkOrAsset.type === 'asset') {
            console.log('Asset', chunkOrAsset);
        } else{
            console.log('Chunk', chunkOrAsset.modules);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to run I get...

> error: relative import path "path" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ Imported from "https://unpkg.com/rollup@2.26.11/dist/es/rollup.js"

I also tried

```
import rollup from "https://unpkg.com/rollup";
```

but I get...

> error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/rollup' does not provide an export named 'default'

finally I tried...

```
import * as rollup from "https://unpkg.com/rollup";
```

But I get...

```
error: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
```

How do I get rollup to work with Deno?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but try prefixing the line with a `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: The short answer is you can't. Rollup uses the I/O module like `fs` and `path` which only available in Nodejs. Unless you found a way to shim/polyfill those modules.

Comment: nodejs != deno; they are not meant to be compatible. You need to wait till rollup is ported to deno.

Answer (score 1):

An effort to port rollup to Deno was started in January 2021, so this problem is now solvable. You can import the deno-rollup module and then use it with the same API as rollup.

Here is a version of your original code which runs under Deno:

```
import { rollup } from "https://deno.land/x/drollup@2.42.3%2B0.17.1/mod.ts";

const bundle = await rollup({
  input: "./index.mjs",
});

const { output } = await bundle.generate({
  format: "esm",
  sourcemap: "inline",
});

for (const chunkOrAsset of output) {
  if (chunkOrAsset.type === "asset") {
    console.log("Asset", chunkOrAsset);
  } else {
    console.log("Chunk", chunkOrAsset.modules);
  }
}
```

You can find multiple examples of using the deno-rollup port on their repository: https://github.com/cmorten/deno-rollup

Please note that Deno's runtime compilation API is considered an unstable API, which means that you must use the `--unstable` flag when running Deno in order to make it available. For example: `deno run --unstable --allow-read=. build.ts`